# Is it a bad practice to use JSON strings as keys of objects?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, json

On languages such as `Haskell`, most datatypes have instances which allow their values to be used as keys of structures such as `Maps`. JavaScript has reasonably fast maps, there called objects, but those only accept string keys. Is there any conceptual issue, or anything else to be worried of, in using JSON strings as keys of objects in order to emulate what Haskell does? I.e.,

```
var point = {"x": 7, "y": 8, "z": 9};
var pointColor = {};
pointColor[JSON.stringify(point)] = "blue";
```

Comment: What sort of conceptual issues or worries did you have in mind?

Comment: I wonder if 1. it is slow and 2. there is a better alternative.

Comment: I'd worry about the ordering of keys. `{"x": 7, "y": 8}` and `{"y": 8, "x": 7}` are different strings, yet equivalent as far as JSON is concerned. You should check the `JSON.stringify` documentation to see if it makes stronger guaranteed about the string representation it produces than the JSON format requires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On languages such as `Haskell`, most datatypes have instances which allow their values to be used as keys of structures such as `Maps`.

It's the same in ECMAScript. Any object, including primitives, can be used as the key in a [`Map`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects). Even `NaN`, even though `NaN !== NaN // true` does the right thing and can be reasonably used as the key in a `Map`.

> JavaScript has reasonably fast maps, there called objects, but those only accept string keys.

They also accept [`Symbol`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol-objects) keys.

Plus, ECMAScript *does* have a native `Map` data type as well.

> Is there any conceptual issue, or anything else to be worried of, in using JSON strings as keys of objects in order to emulate what Haskell does?

Different objects may have the same JSON representation, and the same object may have multiple JSON representations.

The easiest solution would be to use the standard `Map` data type:

```
const point = {x: 7, y: 8, z: 9};
const pointColor = new Map();
pointColor.set(point, "blue");

for (let [{x, y, z}, color] of pointColor) console.log(`{x: ${x}, y: ${y}, z: ${z}} = ${color}`);
// {x: 7, y: 8, z: 9} = blue
```

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is a Map, not an object:
[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

You need to check if the support you need to provide fits with the Map supported browsers, but that´s what you really want as objects only take strings or symbols as keys while a map can take anything

Here is an example of its usage:

```
  var point1 = {"x": 7, "y": 8, "z": 9};
  var point2 = {"x": 6, "y": 5, "z": 4};

  var pointColor = new Map();
  pointColor.set(point1,'blue');
  pointColor.set(point2,'red');
  console.log(pointColor, pointColor.get(point1))
```

Comment: Nice timing :-D

Comment: @JörgWMittag haha, created account on programmers just to answer this as I saw in codereview. The string template you used is nice :)